# How can I populate textbox based on combobox selection in Anglar?

Tags: angular, input, combobox, textbox, fill

So, I have a combobox and I want my textboxes to be automatically filled whenever I choose something from the combobox. My combobox is named Aircraft type and it should automatically fill the textboxes named 'number of motors and MTOW' and the combobox named 'Type of Motor'. They are all coming from an API and they are all related with each other.
Here is the code for my combobox and textboxes:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="width-4">
          <mat-label>Aircraft Type (ICAO)</mat-label>
          <mat-select formControlName="aircraftType" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let item of aircraftTypes" [value]="item.value">
              {{ item.label }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select> </mat-form-field
        ><br />
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="width-3">
          <mat-label>Number of Motors</mat-label>
          <input
            maxlength="50"
            matInput
            formControlName="numberMotors"
            placeholder="Number of Motors"
            required
          />
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="width-3">
          <mat-label>Type of Motor</mat-label>
          <mat-select formControlName="typeMotors" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let item of motorTypes" [value]="item.value">
              {{ item.label }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="width-3">
          <mat-label>MTOW (kg)</mat-label>
          <input
            maxlength="50"
            matInput
            formControlName="mtow"
            placeholder="MTOW"
            required
          />
        </mat-form-field>
```

[image: here is the screenshot of my combobox('Aircraft Type')]

[image: here are the sample of the items to be filled]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using reactive forms, you can just set the values to the corresponding form controls whenever your `aircraftType` control changes it value.

```
@Component({...})
export class AircraftFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public form:FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    aircraftType: '',
    numberMotors: '',
    typeMotors: '',
    mtow: ''
  });

  // Cleanup, not nescessary but a best practice
  private _destroyed$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  constructor(
    private fb:FormBuilder, 

    // Assuming you get your JSON from a service similiar to this and find the value for a given aircraftType by a method called `getValuesForAircraftType`
    private aircraftApi:AircraftApi 
  ) {}
 
  public ngOnInit():void {
    // Subscribe to the valueChanges of your aircraftType, this will trigger whenever you select something for "aircraftType" (=> the value of aircraftType" changes)
    this.form.get('aircractType').valueChanges
      .pipe(
        // Cleanup when destroyed, not strictly nescessary but a best practice
        takeUntil(this._destroyed),

        // Assuming your API returns an observable, use switchMap to cancel previous request when value changes before this the last one finishes
        // If your API does NOT return an observable but the value itself, use 'map' instead of 'switchMap'
        switchMap(aircraftType => this.aircraftApi.getValuesForAircraftType(aircraftType)),
        
      )
      // Using destructoring on the parameter to make this more readable, you can also just call the parameter something like "values" and use it as "values.numberMotors" and so on.
      .subscribe(({ numberMotors, typeMotor, mtow })=> {
        // Set the values form your JSON to your form controls
        this.form.get('numberMotors').setValue(numberMotors);
        this.form.get('typeMotors').setValue(typeMotor);
        this.form.get('mtow').setValue(mtow);
      });
  }

  public ngOnDestroy():void {
    this._destroyed.next();
    this._destroyed.complete();
  }
}
```